# ESXi to Laptop via USB-To-Ethernet Adapter Issue

Tags: vmware-workstation, esxi, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell R620 server and has the NIC connected to a USB-To-Ethernet Adapter which is connected to the Laptop via USB. I can access the Dell Server and ESXi from the Laptop via the USB-To-Ethernet Adapter. I'm trying to get the ESXi server to connect to the internet via the Laptop through VMware Workstation.

Network Diagram - https://i.ibb.co/xYjxjZg/Dell-01.png

Network Address is 192.168.0.0/24

From the diagram:

1 Can ping 3, 4, 5

2 Cannot ping 3, 4, 5

5 Can ping 4, nothing else, I want 5 to ping all the way to the internet

Any thoughts why this is not working.

Comment: What is routing between the networks?  You need to tell the Dell how to get from 192.168.10.x to 192.168.47.x   A host-only network isn't going to be able to ping anything outside of the host, per the name.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to understand as I just checked yesterday, the USB-To-Ethernet Adapter has a pre-set Default Gateway of 0.0.0.0 so I'm understanding that means all networks can pass through, if this is true, what should be the Dell's Default Gateway as the Dell Server is directly connected to the USB-To-Ethernet Adapter which is connected to my Laptop via USB.